# How to view image list in Tex Studio Side Panel?

Tags: table-of-contents, graphics

I'm using TextStudio for writing a book (300 pages). I need to navigate (searching) image in the previous page. I wonder if there is a way so that i can see list of image just like TOC in the side panel of my textstudio. Is that any way to make that possible?
[image]